omitting generics in extension methods
Following is the starting code structure
public abstract class ChildBase;
public class Parent1Child : ChildBase;
public class Parent2Child : ChildBase;

public class ParentBase<T1>
    where T1 : ChildBase
{
    public List<ChildBase> Children = new List<ChildBase>();
}

public class Parent1 : ParentBase<Parent1Child>;

I would like to create an extension method for ef core's EntityTypeBuilder so I am able to extend the entity in a generic way
Following are the attempts:
public static class ParentExtensions
{
    public static void Test1<T>(this ParentBase<T> parent)
        where T : ChildBase
    {
        var children = parent.Children;
    }
}

public static class EfExtensions
{
    public static void Test2<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : ParentBase<ChildBase>
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Children).WithOne();
    }

    public static void Test3<TEntity, TChild>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : ParentBase<TChild>
        where TChild : ChildBase
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Children).WithOne();
    }
}

for the scenario when I want to invoke the extension method directly on the object - the generics are implied (omitted) and compiler does not complain:
var parent = new Parent1();
parent.Test1(); // works

but when I try to invoke the extension method on a builder - the compiler starts to complain  unless I explicitly provide the generic types!
EntityTypeBuilder<Parent1> builder;
builder.Test2(); // wrong
builder.Test3(); // wrong
builder.Test3<Parent1, Parent1Child>(); // works!

Why is it required to provide the generic explicitly when invoking the builder extension method? I think that passing the child class type is redundant and therefore should be omitted.. Any way to fix it?

for Test2 the answer is ParentBase<Parent1Child> is not ParentBase<ChildBase> and there is no inheritance between them

For Test3, there is no TChild parameter, so the generic parameter is not deduced. The compiler does not use the generic constraints to help deduce types or for method resolution, probably because it is difficult.

The only way for Test2 ,afaik,  is to make parentbase interface and with variance it should work (vide IEnumerable<>)

any reason public List<ChildBase> Children = new List<ChildBase>(); is not public List<T1> Children = new List<T1>(); ?

for Test2 the Parent1Child inherits from an abstract class ChildBase so I don't see how this statement is true. Isn't it the same concept as with interfaces? you could define IParent as a parameter to a method then pass the derived class as an argument to this method..

Just because Parent1Child inherits from ChildBase does not mean that ParentBase<Parent1Child> is a ParentBase<ChildBase>. They are completely unrelated, at least in this context. See variance for the rules governing conversions between generic interfaces.

It's a covariance issue
ParentBase<Parent1Child> 

is not a subclass of
ParentBase<ChildBase>

In C# you can only declare covariance generic type in interface
public interface IParent<out T1> // out is here for covariance
{
    // List of ChildBase as you did in ParentBase
    List<ChildBase> Children { get; }
}

public class ParentBase<T1> : IParent<T1>
  where T1: ChildBase
{
    List<ChildBase> Children { get; } = new List<ChildBase>();
}

public static class EfExtensions
{
    public static void Test2<TEntity>(this EntityTypeBuilder<TEntity> builder)
        where TEntity : class, IParent<ChildBase>
    {
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Children).WithOne();
    }
}

EntityTypeBuilder<Parent1> builder;
builder.Test2(); // it compile

Be aware that there is restriction when using covariance, for exemple you won't be able to declare a List<T1> in the interface (but a IReadonlyList<T1> is allowed)
For more information you can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier

in the example you've provided an error is thrown when configuring the Ef model
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The collection navigation 'Children' cannot be added to the entity type 'Parent1' because its CLR type 'IEnumerable<Parent1Child>' does not implement 'IEnumerable<ChildBase>'. Collection navigations must implement IEnumerable<> of the related entity.'
surprisingly, no such exception is thrown when I use the variant of the extension that accepts 2 generics. e.g. this must be one of those limitations you've mentioned..

public interface IParent<out T1>     where T1 : ChildBase {     IEnumerable<T1> Children { get; } }
